# For-each and map in Scheme

Tags: dictionary, foreach, scheme, racket

Are there any difference between these 2 functions in scheme?I am using Dr Racket R5RS language to make a simulator game and I could not decide which one is better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`for-each` evaluates the given function on the list elements left-to-right, and discards the return value of the function. It's ideal for doing side-effecting things to each element of the list.

`map` evaluates the given function on the list elements in no specific order (though most implementations will use either right-to-left or left-to-right), and saves the return value of the function to return to the caller. It's ideal for doing pure-functional processing on each element of the list.

If the return value of `map` is not going to get used, it is better to use `for-each` instead. That way, it doesn't have to bother collecting the return values from the function calls.

(Aside: in Clojure, the return value of `map` is a lazy sequence, which means the given function is only invoked for the elements being materialised.)

---

Technical implementation details. A simplified one-list version of `for-each` is usually implemented like this:

```
(define (for-each func lst)
  (let loop ((rest lst))
    (unless (null? rest)
      (func (car rest))
      (loop (cdr rest)))))
```

Really straightforward, and guarantees left-to-right order. Contrast with a simplified one-list version of `map`:

```
(define (map func lst)
  (let recur ((rest lst))
    (if (null? rest)
        '()
        (cons (func (car rest)) (recur (cdr rest))))))
```

In Scheme, the evaluation order for function arguments is not specified. So for an expression like `(foo (bar) (baz) (qux))`, the calls to `bar`, `baz`, and `qux` can occur in any order, but they will all complete before `foo` is called.

In this case, the `(func (car rest))` can happen first, or it may happen after `(recur (cdr rest))`. It's not guaranteed either way. This is why people say that `map` does not guarantee an evaluation order.

Answer (score 5):

There is a big difference: `map` returns the list containing the results of applying the given procedure on the elements of the list (or lists), while `for-each` returns void.

```
> (for-each (λ (x) (add1 x)) '(1 2 3))
> (map (λ (x) (add1 x)) '(1 2 3))
'(2 3 4)
```

You use `map` whenever you need the result of the computation and you use `for-each` when you're interested in the side effects of that procedure.

The second important difference is that `for-each` guarantees you that the given procedure is applied on the elements in order. For `map`, although the list returned respects the order of the original list[s], it is not guaranteed that the calls were made in order.

more [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html?q=for-each#%25_idx_582)

Comment: In non-Racket Scheme, are there side effects? What does `for-each` do in MIT-Scheme?

Comment: @SeanLetendre As I understand it, the explicit point of `for-each` is the side effects - that's why the order is guaranteed. It's the same in all Schemes.