# Scheme code for fermat's Factorization

Tags: scheme

I am trying to learn scheme by implementing few algorithms.

```
FermatFactor(N): // N should be odd

    a ← ceil(sqrt(N))
    b2 ← a*a - N
    while b2 isn't a square:

            a ← a + 1 // equivalently: b2 ← b2 + 2*a + 1
            b2 ← a*a - N // a ← a + 1

    endwhile
    return a - sqrt(b2) // or a + sqrt(b2)
```

I am trying to implement the above algorithm in scheme. I am stuck on the while loop. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a `while` loop, in Scheme, you would just use recursion. Scheme has tail recursion, so recursion is just as performant as looping constructs in other languages.

Specifically, in this case, you would likely use something called "named let", which makes creating inline recursion easy. A direct translation of the above code to Scheme would result in this:

```
(define (fermat-factor n)
  (let* ((a (ceiling (sqrt n)))
         (b (- (* a a) n)))
    (let loop ()
      (cond
        ((not (integer? (sqrt b)))
         (set! a (+ a 1))
         (set! b (- (* a a) n))
         (loop))))
    (- a (sqrt b))))
```

This really isn't very idiomatic, though, since it uses mutation (the calls to `set!`), which is entirely unnecessary in this algorithm. A more idiomatic approach would look like this:

```
(define (fermat-factor* n)
  (let* ((a0 (ceiling (sqrt n)))
         (b0 (- (* a0 a0) n)))
    (let loop ((a a0)
               (b b0))
      (if (integer? (sqrt b))
          (- a (sqrt b))
          (loop (+ a 1)
                (- (* a a) n))))))
```

(The usage of the initial `let*` is necessary because named let does not permit sequential bindings in the style of `let*`, and `let*` does not support the named let pattern.)

See also [What is "named let" and how do I use it to implement a map function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29594516/465378)

Comment: Thanks so much. I am more of a c# programmer. Understanding Scheme is bit difficult for me.

Comment: You could have used internal definitions for `a0` and `b0`, but `let*` is fine too. Also, personally, I prefer to use `integer-sqrt` (or `exact-integer-sqrt` as it's called in R6RS) so that no floating-point numbers are involved.